# Netty SSL headers

Tags: java, ssl, https, netty

I hate having to ask this question as I'm sure the answer is out there but as I said once before, it's disappointing that I don't find the Netty Documentation very helpful.

Anyways, I've built a Java Web Server that uses Netty for both HTTP and HTTPS connections, obviously. The server serves up both static and dynamic content which can be accessed though several virtual hosts (plus direct IP). I've successfully implemented SSL server wide using a single cert but since my server is meant to host virtual hosts and potentially a different SSL cert for each virtual host, I need to know the requested domain before the SSL handshake starts so I can properly access the correct cert but as I'm being told SSL also encrypts the headers and unfortunately I don't see the headers until after the handshake is finished (which is when the messageReceived method is called within my Handler class).

So can anyone please suggest how I can overcome this issue? Do I need to negotiate the initial SSL connection then renegotiate using the proper certificate or something? How does Apache handle this? Help is greatly appreciated. FYI, I'm using Netty 5.0.0 Alpha2.

Comment: You need to look at the local address of the socket channel to see to which host it was addressed.

Comment: Except, I'm looking for the virtual host, such as example.com which is routed using DNS. Looking at the local address will only reveal the server's IP or hostname.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so for maybe a personal first, I found the answer just after posting this question and that was after searching Google for the last several hours. So I will share what I found in hopes that I can help others.

After finding out that Apache uses SNI to map virtual hosts to multiple certs, I found that Netty has a class named SniHandler and apparently server side SNI support is mostly only available in Java 8. I just recently updated my required minimum version to Java 8, so all good there. After messing around with the class a bit I was able to easily put SniHandler between my server wide SSL implementation and add additional certificates for each virtual host. This is why I have a love/hate relationship with Netty, it usually has a great builtin solution but I have such a hard time finding it.

Just in case it helps here is the my source code, you can find my entire web server project at https://github.com/ChioriGreene/ChioriWebServer

SslContextFactory.class

```
public class SslContextFactory
{
    private static DomainNameMapping<SslContext> mapping;

    private SslContextFactory()
    {

    }

    public static void addMapping( String hostname, SslContext context )
    {
        // Using *.example.com will include all subdomains, including the root TLD
        mapping.add( hostname, context );
    }

    public static SniHandler getSniHandler()
    {
        return new SniHandler( mapping );
    }

    public static void init() throws StartupException
    {
        final File sslCert = new File( "server.crt" );
        final File sslKey = new File( "server.key" );
        final String sslSecret = "SslSecret";

        if ( !sslCert.exists() )
            throw new StartupException( "We could not start the HTTPS Server because the '" + sslCert.getName() + "' (aka. SSL Cert) file does not exist. Please generate one and reload the server, or disable SSL in the configs." );

        try
        {
            NetworkManager.getLogger().info( String.format( "Initalizing the SslContext using cert '%s', key '%s', and hasSecret? %s", sslCert.getName(), sslKey.getName(), ( sslSecret != null && !sslSecret.isEmpty() ) ) );

            SslContext sslContext;
            if ( sslSecret == null || sslSecret.isEmpty() )
                sslContext = SslContext.newServerContext( sslCert, sslKey );
            else
                sslContext = SslContext.newServerContext( sslCert, sslKey, sslSecret );

            mapping = new DomainNameMapping<SslContext>( sslContext );
        }
        catch ( SSLException e )
        {
            throw new StartupException( "We could not start the HTTPS Server because " + e.getMessage(), e );
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            throw new StartupException( "We could not start the HTTPS Server for an uncaught exception", e );
        }
    }
}
```

HttpsInitializer.class

```
public class HttpsInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>
{
    @Override
    protected void initChannel( SocketChannel ch ) throws Exception
    {
        ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();

        try
        {
            p.addLast( SslContextFactory.getSniHandler() );
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            NetworkManager.shutdownHttpsServer();
            throw new IllegalStateException( "The SSL engine failed to initalize", e );
        }

        p.addLast( "decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder() );
        p.addLast( "aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator( 104857600 ) );
        p.addLast( "encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder() );
        p.addLast( "deflater", new HttpContentCompressor() );
        p.addLast( "handler", new HttpsHandler() );
    }
}
```